# Grab specific image when click on image to enlarge image

Tags: jquery

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1muwoftt/)

HTML

```
    <div class="col-4.col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
     <div class="ratio-14-16">
       <div class="productImg" style="background-image:url('http://paperbotz.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/hello_kitty001.png'); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;width:200px; height: 200px">
       </div>
       <div class="info uppercase text-center">
        <span data-image>View Image</span>
       </div>
    </div>
   <div class="details">Test 2</div>
<div class="img-panel-view.cly-abs-center" style="background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; backgroung-position: center center"></div>
```

JQuery

```
$('[data-image]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var imgPartBg = $(this).closest().css('background-image');
    alert(imgPartBg);

    $('.img-panel-view').css('background-image', 'url(' + bg + ')');
});
```

There will be dynamic images in gallery, and when click on one of them, it should grab the specific background image in the specific div to be displayed in full on overlay. They will have the full absolute paths. Replace() will not be in use.

Tried using closest() or siblings('.productImg') and it returns undefined. 
How to grab the background image when click specific image?

**Updated**

One more similar problem. How to grab details? Tried closest, prev, parent or siblings and it doesn't grab the detail div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('[data-image]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var imgPartBg = $(this).parent().prev('div.productImg').css('background-image'),
        path = imgPartBg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');

    $('.img-panel-view').css('background-image', 'url(' + path + ')');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your quick help. but tested, it returns undefined and replace is no such property. see fiddle with your answer - http://jsfiddle.net/1muwoftt/1/

Comment: i tried parent().sibling('.productImg') and it seems to be working

Comment: @jeo yeah. that will also work. but I belive .prev() is faster.

Comment: sorry to ask but if wanted to find details outside div, would it be closest()? Because try both siblings or closest() it is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Try this to retrieve the URL of the "background-image" http://jsfiddle.net/76oshjrk/

HTML slightly updated:

```
<span id="data-image">View Image</span>        <!-- added id tag -->
```

JQuery slightly modified:

```
$('.productImg').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var src = $(this).css('background-image');       //get "background-image" url
   var myURL = src.slice(4,src.length-1);         //remove "url(" and ")"
   $('#data-image').html("url: " +myURL);         //full url of "background-image"

});
```

Comment: check myURL in alert and it doesn't show any path. thanks for the help though

Comment: Joe, it seems to work in jsFiddle, once you click the image, please see http://jsfiddle.net/76oshjrk/1/   i added the alert(myURL)